# How do I turn off right-paren on its own line in IntelliJ IDEA with EditorConfig in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editorconfig

I am using Intellij IDEA 2020.3.1 for Java work.  We have a project requirement to use EditorConfig to define code style, and Intellij is therefore set to have EditorConfig settings override settings in the editor preferences.

I am trying (and failing) to figure out how to have the closing parenthesis of a multi-line method call **NOT** be on its own line.

In other words, I want

```
foo(
    a,
    b,
    c);
```

and **NOT**

```
foo(
    a,
    b,
    c
);
```

I have tried a whole bunch of settings in the `.editorconfig` file that look promising, but have had no luck.

I thought that this would do the trick but it didn't work.

```
ij_java_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
```

So which Intellij IDEA EditorConfig settings will do the trick?

Also, is there a list anywhere of all the EditorConfig settings that Intellij IDEA supports and their definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. I think the call argument wrapping and new line after left parenthesis is what you are after.

Here are the fields I updated in `.editorconfig` for this.

```
ij_java_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = true
ij_java_call_parameters_wrap = split_into_lines
```

The resulting code after formatting looks as below;

```
 public class Foo {
    public static void storm(int w, int x, int y, int z) {
        System.out.println("w = " + w + ", x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        storm(
                1,
                2,
                4,
                5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will those settings do that to _all_ method calls or just ones that are multiline?  I want single-line calls to be left as single-line calls.

Comment: Didn't you try?

Comment: I did try it and it did just what I was worried about.
It turned `foo(a, b, c);` into a multi-line call.  That's not what I want.  I want single-line calls left alone and multi-line calls formatted with the closing paren on the same line as the last parameter.